# groupby with visualization in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My data frame looks like -

```
state       material
bihar          a
wb             b
ap             a
bihar          a
bihar          d
ap             b
```

I want data frame looks like -

```
state        state_contribution     material_a  material_b  material_c  material_d
bihar            3/6                   2/6         0          0             1/6
wb               1/6                   1/6         0          0              0
ap               2/6                   1/6         1/6        0              0
```

based on that I want to draw some meaningful story (based on some pie or bar graph). Means state wise bihar contribution is very high, then ap and wb. or material_a contribution very high in bihar.

How to do it in python

Comment: Removed `matplotlib` and `seaborn` tags as they have nothing to do with the question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) on each group. Use [`df.add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to add `material_` to each column and [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add `state_contribution` which is sum over axis 1.

```
df = df.groupby('state')['material'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).\
                          add_prefix('material_').\
                          assign(state_contribution=lambda x:x.sum(1))

df
       material_a  material_b  material_d  state_contribution
state
ap            1.0         1.0         0.0                 2.0
bihar         2.0         0.0         1.0                 3.0
wb            0.0         1.0         0.0                 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) in first step with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add also some non exist materials from list, then use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last add new column with sum by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
mat = ['a','b','c', 'd']
df = (pd.crosstab(df['state'], df['material'])
        .reindex(mat,axis=1, fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('material_')
        .assign(state_contribution = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))
print (df)
material  material_a  material_b  material_c  material_d  state_contribution
state                                                                       
ap                 1           1           0           0                   2
bihar              2           0           0           1                   3
wb                 0           1           0           0                   1
```

If dont need add all materials only remove `reindex`:

```
df = (pd.crosstab(df['state'], df['material'])
        .add_prefix('material_')
        .assign(state_contribution = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))
print (df)
material  material_a  material_b  material_d  state_contribution
state                                                           
ap                 1           1           0                   2
bihar              2           0           1                   3
wb                 0           1           0                   1
```

Last if need divide values by length of original data:

```
mat = ['a','b','c', 'd']
df = (pd.crosstab(df['state'], df['material'])
        .reindex(mat,axis=1, fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('material_')
        .assign(state_contribution = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
        .div(len(df)))
print (df)
material  material_a  material_b  material_c  material_d  state_contribution
state                                                                       
ap          0.166667    0.166667         0.0    0.000000            0.333333
bihar       0.333333    0.000000         0.0    0.166667            0.500000
wb          0.000000    0.166667         0.0    0.000000            0.166667
```

---

```
df = (pd.crosstab(df['state'], df['material'])
        .add_prefix('material_')
        .assign(state_contribution = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
        .div(len(df)))
print (df)
material  material_a  material_b  material_d  state_contribution
state                                                           
ap          0.166667    0.166667    0.000000            0.333333
bihar       0.333333    0.000000    0.166667            0.500000
wb          0.000000    0.166667    0.000000            0.166667
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(df.groupby('state')['material'].value_counts().unstack('material', fill_value=0).add_prefix('material_').assign(state_contribution=lambda x: x.sum(1)).reset_index()).reset_index()
```

[image]